# Perl regex issue , last character truncated

Tags: regex, perl

Have a strange issue with my regex.

My regex is truncating the last character , in the example below it should return the value 32 but it is instead returning 3.

Note that the value could be up to 10 digits!!!

```
$word = "thisisit=";
$line = "hello thisisit=32 byefornow ";   

if ($line =~ m/$word(.*?)\d /) 
{
    print $1;    #returns 3 instead of 32
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
if ($line =~ /$word(\d+)/) # This will capture all numbers after your $word
{
    print $1;   
}
```

You can also refine to:

```
if ($line =~ /$word\s*(\d+)/) # In case you're having like "thisisit=   32 byefornow"
```

Or, to capture everything and stop after first white space:

```
if ($line =~ /$word(.+?)\s/) 
{
    print $1;   
}
```

Comment: @user2574678 Also, given that your `$word` is meant to be a literal string, you should use [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) on it inside the regex.  `if ($line =~ /\Q$word\E(\d+)/)`  Your current value doesn't have any regex special characters in it, but you should get in the habit of ensuring that literals really are treated as such in a regex.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask for it to return zero or any number of digits:

```
($line =~ m/$word(.*?)\d* /)
```

At least one digit: \d+

Two digits: \d{2}

I'm not sure what you are looking for here, in terms of the specs.

Comment: That will return the last 2 digits of the number. If you don't know how many digits it will be I would probably use something like `m/${word}=(\d+) /`

Comment: What's been missed in this answer is the fact that `$1` can match anything non-greedily in the question. The `\d` should be inside the brackets, not outside